# How to exit a for loop on click function in javascript?

Tags: javascript, html, for-loop

I am trying to exit a for loop on a click function in javascript. But somewhere I am not getting the correct way to do so. Please take a look to my code and help me to get out of this problem.

What I am trying to do is want to show different div elements inside the li element with a click on li and want to hide the same with a click on div.

here is the [link](http://jsfiddle.net/LiranBo/p2oc6u93/) for jsfiddle

Here is the code below :: (html)

```
<ul>
    <li>
       <div style="position: fixed; width: 400px; height: 400px; background-color: #0c6; display: none;"></div>
    </li>
    <li></li>
    <li></li>
</ul>
```

Style

```
ul {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
}

ul li {
    list-style: none;
    float: left;
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
    background-color: green;
    border: 1px solid;
}
```

javascript

```
var a = document.getElementsByTagName('li');

for (i = 0; i < a.length; i++) {
    a[i].onclick = function () {
        var b = this.getElementsByTagName('div')[0];

        setTimeout(function () {
            b.style.display = 'block';
        }, 1000);

        b.onclick = function () {
            this.style.display = 'none';    
        };
    };
}
```

Comment: Instead of loop you can use _setInterval_  method and perform the required task and clear the interval when the click event fires!

Or second option is that you take a global flag and set it to true. Check for the flag and if its true break the loop.

Comment: You can't exit the for loop from inside the click function, because the loop will have already finished before the click function is called.

Comment: The loop executes on it's own and doesn't have any link to the click event. Please create a fiddle and show us where it fails.

Comment: here is the [link](http://jsfiddle.net/subhajit06/cps1ya2m/) for jsfiddle

Comment: @SubhajitDas errm wheres the rest of your fiddle, its only got HTML?

Comment: Sorry, 
here is the updated version
[link](http://jsfiddle.net/subhajit06/cps1ya2m/1/)

Comment: I think its not the loop issue, its actually the  click issue, whenever click on the div element its being clicked on the list again